# Android Displaying FullScreen Slider Images

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

I have a gridviewImages dispalyed on Android screen.
My Requirement is to Slide the FullScreen Images

Here My code:

**ImageAdapter :**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

   // Constructor
   public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      return mThumbIds.length;
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
   }

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView;
      if (convertView == null) {
      imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
      imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
      } else {
      imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }

      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
      return imageView;
   }

   // Keep all Images in array
   public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
      R.drawable.cn1, R.drawable.cn2,
      R.drawable.cn3, R.drawable.cn4,
      R.drawable.cn5, R.drawable.cn6,
      R.drawable.cn7, R.drawable.cn8,
      R.drawable.cn9, R.drawable.cn10,
      R.drawable.cn11, R.drawable.cn12

   };
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
          gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
          gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                      int position, long id) {

                  // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
                  Intent i = 
                  new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
                  // Pass image index
                  i.putExtra("id", position);
                  Log.d("onCreateMain>>","OnCreateMain");

                  startActivity(i);
              }
          });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**SingleViewActivity:**

```
public class SingleViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_view);
        Log.d("onCreate>>","OnCreate");

        // Get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        Log.d("Position>>>","Position"+position);
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SingleView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }

}
```

Layout XMl Files:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

single_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/SingleView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Requirement is to Slide the FullScreen Images,Could any one help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ViewPager will let you 'slide' between fragments, which is exactly the effect you are trying to achieve. Just turn your current SingleViewActivity into a fragment:

```
public class SingleViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int resource = getArguments().getInt("image");

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SingleView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }
}
```

You will need a PagerAdapter to generate this fragments as needed.

```
public class ImagesPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.cn1, R.drawable.cn2,
        R.drawable.cn3, R.drawable.cn4,
        R.drawable.cn5, R.drawable.cn6,
        R.drawable.cn7, R.drawable.cn8,
        R.drawable.cn9, R.drawable.cn10,
        R.drawable.cn11, R.drawable.cn12
    };

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("image", mThumbIds[i]);

        SingleViewFragment fragment = new SingleViewFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
}
```

Then you will need an activity that contains a single ViewPager, set as its adapter an instance of the ImagesPagerAdapter, and give it a position in which to start.

```
public class SingleViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager);

        // Selected image id
        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagesPagerAdapter(this));
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

Where activiy_pager is just a layout containing the ViewPager you need.

```
<ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/pager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Could you please how to start singleviewFragment from My MainActicity, if i click on Gridview Item,Could you elaborate the flow?

Comment: Your MainActivity is fine as it is, just remember to use the Activity context to create the intent instead of the Application one, as you are doing now. The PagerAdapter will instantiate the fragments for you as they are needed. I have completed the code.

Comment: I have tried your updated code,but getting nullpointerexception,Could you give your EmailId so that I can mail you my Application

Comment: I have uploaded a working example based in your code over here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8p8gdq273wyeuwk/exViewPager.zip

Comment: Thanks for your effort