# How to display slide full screen image from SD card in Android

Tags: android, imageview

**Need help!**
I want to display images on full screen in Android and change by sliding.

When the application will run, it will load all images from SD card and direct display on the screen. and the user can change image by swipe.

I am following the tutorial but can't see the image since its very complex: [click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

If someone please help me? You can download my code from here please: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lakfpxw80t653fx/ImageViewTestProj.rar)

Comment: Can you provide the code directly in your question? And if it is too big to be included in a question, you should try to give the relevant part.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057996/android-displaying-fullscreen-slider-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

create a `ViewPagerAdapter`

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(<your_content>) {
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ImageFragment.newInstance(<your_content>.getImageId(id));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return <your_content>.size();
    }
}
```

then an `ImageFragment`

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ImageFragment newInstance(int image /*or url*/) {
        final ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("image", image);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public ImageFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(<your_layout>, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(<image_view>);

        imageView.setImage(getArguments().getInt("image")); // Use appropriate function
    }
}
```

and an `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(<main_layout>);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(<view_pager>);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(<your_content>);
}
```

To retrieve your images, use something like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, then get their `Uri`.

Comment: Actually I am looking to change the given code. since I am new in Android so it will be difficult for me to set your code in that project. Can you please upload your project in github and provide me the link? then it will be easy for me. thans

Comment: don't you think, viewFlipper will be the best option fr my desired output?

Comment: There's no swipe with `ViewFlipper`, you'll need to add gesture recognition.